# Table row onclick String value shows error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have populated table from database in Ajax using json. But on click edit button only number field are passed to java script function. But when i want to pass  string like name, base64Encoding String not passed
Here is the java script code

```
'<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doGet('+item.pohto+','+item.name+')" > <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> </a>';
```

When I click on edit icon it shows bellow error

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

But when I use only number value it is working.

Please help me to pass string value like image , name

Comment: `onclick="doGet('+item.pohto+'","'+item.name+')"`?

Comment: @guradio i want name & photo to pass value doGet function

Comment: It seems like a typo. you pass **pohto** instead of **photo**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when `item.pohto` and `item.name` are strings that contain spaces, you end up with something like this:

```
onclick="doGet(value one, value two)"
```

which is invalid syntax. You'll have to add quotes to make those values string literals.

```
'<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doGet(\''+item.pohto+'\', \''+item.name+'\')" > <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> </a>'
```

You can also use a string template which will make this easier to read:

```
`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="doGet('${item.pohto}', '${item.name}')" > <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> </a>`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
item.name
```

Might be empty, try checking if item.name has a value

```
onclick="doGet('+item.pohto+''+item.name ? ','+item.name : ''+')"
```

Answer (score 0):

probably `item.pohto` or `item.name` is empty. therefor the function will look like `doGet('value',)` or `doGet(,'value')`.

This will be interpreted as wrong Javascript syntax.

You should set a breakpoint in the console and check how the actual values look like.
Even better: make a function wich will take the full item value and check the existance of the needed attributes in the object for your self like this:

```js
function performDoGet(item) {
  if (item['pohto'] && item['name']) {
    doGet(item.pohto, item.name);
  }
  else {
    console.log("Values are missing");
  }
}
```

and change your clicklistener to following:

```js
'<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="performDoGet(' + item + ')"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>';
```